# Getting all of the messages id's of a Group of messages in python-telegram-bot

Tags: python, python-3.x, telegram-bot, python-telegram-bot

So I have a very big problem with storing multiple id's of messages (specially audios) when I forward multiple of them to my bot.

I've been using the `telegram.Update.message.message_id` to store the ID of the messages that are being sent to my bot, but there is a catch. When I try to forward multiple audios the messages all go as a group, and the bot would only get the first audio `message_id`.

I want it so that I could store all of the `message_id`.

You can check the whole thing on my Github the link is here:
[Project link](https://github.com/sinayzsn/sinaps-music-bot/blob/develop/main.py)

Thanks in advance!

There were some work around's I have tried:

```py
from telegram import Update

...

async def genre_selection(update: Update, context: ContextTypes.DEFAULT_TYPE) -> int:

...

message = update.message

...

# Here are the methods I have tried -->

context.user_data("audio_message_ids", []).append(message.message_id)
print(context.user_data.get("audio_message_ids", []))

# and 
message.reply_to_message.message_id

# and 
msgid_to_str = str(message.message_id)
for i in msgid_to_str:
    context.user_data["audio_message_ids"] = i
    print(context.bot_data.get("audio_message_ids"))
    print(i)

# and
telegram.MessageId.message_id

# and
getup = bot.get_updates()
    song_id = getup[-1].message.message_id
    logger.info(f"the id list is {song_id}")

# and 
id_of_songs = []
id_of_songs.append(Update.message.message_id)
print(f"the id list is {id_of_songs}")
```

But none of them actually work I am very stuck and have no solution for this any more.